# How can probability be equal to pdf times volume of area?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I'm studying pattern recognition and I'm at the part about Kernel density estimators. During the introduction of the subject, the book I'm studying (*Pattern Recognition & Machine Learning by Bishop*) takes for granted something I'm not sure I can understand.

Say we have an unknown pdf $p(x)$ in some D-dimensional space and let us consider some small region $R$ containing $x$. Then, if we make the assumption that $R$ is small enough so that the pdf is roughly constant over the region, we have $$P \approx p(x)V$$ where $V$ is **the volume of $R$**.

I'm completely unaware of how this formula was derived or how the volume $V$ appeared there. Any help woud be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220.  Your equation is one *definition* of a probability density.

Comment: Thanks whuber. I was aware of this definition but as I said in the comments I was confused from the volume term. I think I got it now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple integral approximation. First, think in 1D. The area under a curve $f(x)$ in a very small x-axis segment (e.g. $[x,x+\Delta x]$) is $\approx f(x)\Delta x$; because $f(x)$ is nearly constant across this region. Similarly, in 2D, integral of $f(x,y)$ over a small region is $\approx f(x)\Delta x\Delta y$. In multiple dimensions, all the multiplicands near $f$ is called as *volume*, i.e. $f(x_1,...,x_n)\underbrace{\Delta x_1...\Delta x_n}_V$.

Comment: This is what I thought at first, but I was confused because as you say, when my variable $x$ is a vector of 2 dimensions $x,y$ then indeed the approximation would be $f(x)Δ(x)Δ(y)$. But, isnt this the volume? Since $f(x)$ is the "height" and you multiply it with the other 2 dimensions, say width and depth. Therefore I was confused because I thought, it should be $P = V$ and not $p(x)V$ since the volume requires to multiply $p(x)$ with all the rest dimensions. But its probably an n-dimensional thing that they called volume this product?

Comment: @Thomas, You misinterpret the term volume. In 1D, length of line segment $R$ is the volume. In 2D, area of $R$ is the volume etc. The volume here is not the area/volume under $f(x)$. Informally, think as if it is referred as *hypervolume* of region $R$.

Comment: When you say it like that it makes sense. We get off subject here but, isn't volume the space that a 3d object takes up? And it is $A*h$ where A = area and h = height. Is the concept we use in this question somewhat different from the one I mention here in the comment? Of course we generalize it for more than 3 dimensions.

Comment: The term volume is used for all dimensions, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball

Comment: Thanks for the link, but as you said , in a 3d example the approximation would be $f(x)dxdy$.  Isnt this whole product the volume of a shape? $dxdy$ is the area of $R$ and $f$ is the height. Your answer explained my question, so sorry I keep asking things, just trying to fully understand what you're saying ! :)

Comment: $f(x)dxdy$ is the volume under $f(x)$, but $dxdy$ is the volume of $R$.

Comment: Ok thing I got this! Gotta let it sink in :) Thanks for all the help, very much appreciated. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is how probability density is defined. Probability density is the [*probability per foot*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4223/35989). It is normalized by the area, so that over all the area it integrates to unity. More formally, quoting *All of statistics* by Larry A. Wasserman:

> **2.11 Definition.** *A random variable $X$ is **continuous** if there exists a  function $f_X$ such that $f_X(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$,
>   $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)\, dx = 1$ and for every $a \le b$,*
>
> $$ \mathbb{P}(a < X < b) = \int_a^b f_X(x) \,dx \tag{2.2} $$
>
> *The function $f_X$ is called the **probability density function** (PDF).*

Comment: I'm aware of the definition and it was my first thought. However I was confused for the reason I posted in the above comment, if you'd like to take a look !